# Shadow on custom navigation bar button item clipping to bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a back button item on my navigation bar that I want to use include a drop shadow on but the drop shadow clips to the navbar bounds.  Is it possible shadows extend past the bounds of the navbar?

I've simplified and greatly exaggerated the effect in this example:
[image]

The code for the button looks something like this:

```
    let button = UIButton();
    button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 12);
    button.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.06, green: 0.09, blue: 0.13, alpha: 0.8).cgColor;
    button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    button.layer.shadowRadius = 14;
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0.65, blue:0.57, alpha:1);
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 20;

    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true;
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button);
```

I also set my navigation bar to transparent with the following code:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default);
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage();
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true;
```

I've already tried a setting clipsToBounds and layer.masksToBounds to false on the navigationBar but that doesn't fix the issue.  I figure as a hack I could probably just increase the size of the navigationBar and reposition the button so the shadow doesn't clip the statusBar but hoping someone knows a more ideal solution.

Comment: Have you tried clipToBounds and masksToBounds to false on the button itself?

Comment: Yeah that doesn't help.  One additional piece of information I should include is that this doesn't happen on the root view controller of the UINavgiationController.

Comment: Another clue, you have to have the push controllers with animated set to true to the UINavigationController.

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't think this is good idea to add such a shadow in a navigation bar, but if you want, add the following code in you view controller, it should work.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews.forEach {
        $0.clipsToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work but only once the view controller finishes the push animation.  During the animation it's still obviously clipped so the effect looks bad.  As far as not adding a shadow in the navigation bar, I don't make the design but I could talk to designer to discuss alternatives.